# C# UDP multicast

Tags: c#, udp, windows-ce, multicast

I need multicast sender and receiver like the one described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.multicastoption.aspx#Y1400)

While my multicast sender is desktop app, receivers are PDA devices and use compact framework (Windows CE 5.0). Where should I start digging?

Comment: Or what else method would you advise me to use ? Broadcast would also meet my requirements.

Comment: http://discovertheexperience.blogspot.com/2009/10/windows-embedded-ce-60-r3-connection.html

Answer (score 1):

I would research socket multicast in general first.  It's not specific to CE, so understanding it in general will help.  This could be from a C# specific point of view.  For example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1705/IP-Multicasting-in-C provides a good introduction.  As does http://www.jarloo.com/c-udp-multicasting-tutorial/  I haven't noticed much difference in doing this for CE; but there might be some slight differences.  Once you're familiar with the technology, start making sure the individual types and methods are support in CE 5.